# How to display asterisks (***)

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to create an ATM application using c++ and I want to display asterisks (****) when I input the pin code. I haven't tried anything because I have no idea on how to do it.

Could someone help me?

Comment: How to accomplish that is platform-specific.

Comment: molbdnilo is correct.
What you first need is a function, which takes a character from the keyboard, without echoing it back, like `getch` under Windows. How we start with 'What platform are you trying to do this for?'

Comment: Take a look at [tag:pdcurses] if you want to make something reasonably portable, otherwise, read the API for the platform you're on.

Comment: @StefanPapa That is not a platform, that is an IDE. Which operating system will be running the code you're trying to write? Windows? Linux? Unix? Mac? Solaris?

Comment: i'll be running it on windows

Comment: @StefanPapa In that case, I suggest checking out `_getch()`, which does what you need. Keep looping until the read character is Enter (ASCII code 13) and output an * for each time a letter other than enter has been pressed.

Comment: okay i'll try that. thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. If you're happy with an answer and consider your problem 'solved', please mark it as 'accepted', so others will know that you no longer require help.

Answer (score 2):

A very small program which should help you get started for Windows would go like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char character = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        character = _getch();
        if (character == 13) //Enter
            break;
        else
        {
            putc('*');
            //Do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this code is off the top of my head and still requires the correct includes, but should point you in the right direction.

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-160 for the documentation of `_getch` and `http://www.asciitable.com/` for a list of control codes you might be getting.